# ¿Cómo devolver nombre de archivo en Explorer de W10 con VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vb, visual-basic

tengo un codigo desarrollado, pero hasta ahora solo consigo abrir el explorador de W10 para seleccionar unos archivos, la cosa es que me da error y no se por qué... la cosa es que quiero que me devuelva el nombre de los archivos en un libro de excel. alguien me echa una mano please?
aqui el codigo :

```
Sub OpenExplorerMultiselectFiles()

myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Image Files (*.jpg*;*.png;*), *jpg*;*.png*", , , , True)

If TypeName(myfile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

    file = 11

For i = LBound(mylife) To UBound(mylife)

    Cells(file, 2) = myfile(i)

    file = file + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda incluir el error completo que te da al correr el código

Comment: Voto por cerrar la pregunta ya que es un error tipográfico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el for estás nombrando mal tu array. Es "myfile" y tu pones "mylife", jajaja:

```
Sub OpenExplorerMultiselectFiles()

myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Image Files (*.jpg*;*.png;*), *jpg*;*.png*", , , , True)

If TypeName(myfile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

    file = 11

For i = LBound(myfile) To UBound(myfile)

    Cells(file, 2) = myfile(i)

    file = file + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: _Suena bon jovi_